# how can i write char type matrix in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, matrix

**I write this code:**

```
var matrix: [[Character]] = []

matrix[1][1] = "#"

print(matrix)
```

I get this error:

```
***Fatal error: Index out of range***
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: What do you expect `print(matrix)` to return in this case? Is there an element at `matrix[0][0]`, or is this matrix 1-indexed? What should `matrix[2][2]` return? As others have noted, this is not a matrix; it is an array of arrays. But if you will explain the interface you're looking for and how you plan to call it (and what kinds of performance vs easy-of-use you're looking for), it's possible to build a wide variety of matrix-like types in Swift. But you need to be very specific on the behaviors you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, your array is empty. So `matrix[1][1]` at the position there is no element is available and you can not add or update the element at this position. Also, the array starts from 0 indexes.

So here you need to first append some elements and then you can get and update the element.

```
var matrix: [[Character]] = []
matrix.append(contentsOf: [["a", "b"], ["a", "b"]])
matrix[1][1] = "#"

print(matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you initially write this -

```
var matrix: [[Character]] = []
```

There are no arrays/entries inside it, it's empty. When you write this -

```
matrix[1][1] = "#"
```

You are telling the program to find an array in the second row, and replace it's second entry with `#`. Since the array is empty, you get the crash.

You can try following -

```
import Foundation

var matrix: [[Character]] = [
    ["A", "B"],
    ["C", "D"]
]

matrix[1][1] = "#"

print(matrix)
// [["A", "B"], ["C", "#"]]
```